# Incremental load Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do an incremental load using ADF, but I got this error message, how to solve it and to do the incremental load in the right way?
Note:the Table name variable is defined through the stored procedure.

[Error Message ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIslv.png)

Stored Procedure:

```
           ALTER PROCEDURE [INT].[usp_write_watermark] 
           @LastModifiedtime datetime, @TableName varchar(50)
            AS

             BEGIN

             UPDATE [log].watermarktable
             SET [WatermarkValue] = @LastModifiedtime
              WHERE [TableName] = @TableName

                END
```

Comment: Have you tried this as a data flow instead? It is much easier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tNWFErnGGU

Comment: The error is because you are referencing a property that does not exist (tablename) from look up activity in stored procedure `write last modified date`. Please provide additional information about what you are trying to in this stored procedure.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT It's required to do it this way without data flow activity

Comment: @SaideepArikontham How can I make the watermark table insert the table name automatically? because unless I insert it manually it won't work..

Comment: Please confirm this: In the given stored procedure, you are passing the values of `LastModifiedtime` and `TableName` from ADF. Is this correct? If so, how are you getting these values